# PHP: Cut array into pieces based on ranges defined in other arrays with start and end value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a booking system for presentation rooms, where the user is able to book the room for an amount of time(this works so far) on a day. The booking info is stored in a database. The selection and display of booked times works fine.

Now I want to display the free slots that are still available, but I can't get an idea on how to do that.

I was thinking about storing all time slots into an array and then, cut the array into pieces based on the already booked times, approximately like this:

```
//initial values
//all timeslots
array = ["07:00", "07:30", "08:00", "08:30", "09:00", ... , "20:00", "20:30", "21:00", "21:30", "22:00"];
//all booked slots with start and end time
booked1 = ["08:00","09:00"];
booked2 = ["11:00","14:30"];
booked3 = ["18:30","21:00"];
bookedn = ["tt:tt", "tt:tt"];
//How "array" should be seperated and saved into new arrays (start and end times for those ranges could also be possible)
array_new2 = ["07:00", "07:30", "08:00"];
array_new2 = ["09:00", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00"];
array_new3 = ["14:30", "15:00", "15:30", "16:00", "16:30", "17:00", "17:30", "18:00", "18:30"];
array_new4 = ["21:00", "21:30", "22:00"];
```

I also included 2 screenshots to show how it looks(1)/should look like(2), to give you a better understanding why/for what I need that.

[how it looks without "free slots"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oTBo.png)

[how I want to display the "free slots"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsEeX.png)

If there is a better/simpler solution, even better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not check with all test cases but I think it will do as per your example.

```
<?php
   $array = ["07:00", "07:30", "08:00", "08:30", "09:00", "09:30",
   "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00", "12:30",
   "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30", "15:00", "15:30",
   "16:00", "16:30", "17:00", "17:30", "18:00", "18:30",
   "19:00", "19:30", "20:00", "20:30", "21:00", "21:30", "22:00"];

  $booked = [
                  ["08:00","09:00"],
                  ["11:00","14:30"],
                  ["18:30","21:00"]
      ];
  $free_slots = [];

  echo '<pre>';
  foreach($booked as $slot){
     $start = 0;
     $index_1 = array_search($slot[0],$array);
     $index_2 = array_search($slot[1],$array);
     $free_slots[] = getSubset($start,$index_1, $index_2);
  }

  if(!empty($array)){
     $free_slots[] = $array;
  }
  print_r($free_slots);

  function getSubset($start, $index_1, $index_2){
      global $array;
      $a = array_slice($array, $start, $index_1+1);
      $array = array_slice($array, $index_2);
      $array = array_values($array);
      return $a;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you vey much!! That was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: it maybe a little bit dirty but it work. you have to change your format a little bit.

```
$all_timeslots = [
    '07:00', '07:30', '08:00', '08:30', '09:00',
    '09:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30',
    '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00',
    '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30',
    '17:00', '17:30', '18:00', '18:30', '19:00',
    '19:30', '20:00', '20:30', '21:00', '21:30',
    '22:00'
];

$bookeds[] = ['08:00', '09:00'];
$bookeds[] = ['11:00', '14:30'];
$bookeds[] = ['18:30', '21:00'];
$bookeds[] = ['tt:tt', 'tt:tt'];

$available_timeslots = [];
foreach ($bookeds as $key => $booked) {
    $touched = false;

    foreach ($all_timeslots as $timeslot) {
        if ($timeslot == $booked[1]) {
            break;
        }

        if ($touched) {
            array_shift($all_timeslots);
        } else {
            $available_timeslots[$key][] = array_shift($all_timeslots);
        }

        if ($timeslot === $booked[0]) {
            $touched = true;
        }
    }
}

return $available_timeslots;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!

That is almost what I wanted to achieve, but I wanted to have the free timeslots in arrays for themselves. Thats what I meant wit **cut into pieces**. Like this:

The first free slot only goes from 07:00 to 08:00 since the first booked slot starts at 08:00. So the array for the first free slot should be ['7:00', '7:30']. The next free slot array would be ['9:30','10:00','10:30'] and so on.

(I hope I explained it clear enough :) )

Comment: @JimmyFloyd007, yes you have explained it clearly. I've updated the code, please try it.

Comment: @JimmyFloyd007 if the answer help you, please click accept.

Comment: Thank you very much for your update! Your approach is great too, but I just could work a little bit better with the code provided in the other answer. None the less, your answer is great too and solves my problem.